# java: simple type conversion

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have written my very first java program on eclipse on windows.I have recently started programming java on linux.

When I try to compile the above program on Linux it does work fine but when I try to do it on windows I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to short
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float

public class TypeDemo {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
            byte b = 8;
            long a = 1000011334;
            int c = 76;
            short s = 99789;

            float f = 99.99;
            double d = 99979.9879;
            boolean bool = true;
            char ch = 'y';

            System.out.println ("b = "+b);
            System.out.println ("a = "+a);
            System.out.println ("c = "+c);
            System.out.println ("s = "+s);
            System.out.println ("f = "+f);
            System.out.println ("d = "+d);
            System.out.println ("bool = "+bool);
            System.out.println ("ch = "+ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: If anything, it is quite strange that this code compiles on Linux. What compiler are you using? Is it really the exact same code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try to compile the above program on Linux it does work fine

That's in fact quite surprising, and I can't buy it. Check it again, it shouldn't.

`short` is a 16-bit signed 2's complement integer. It's maximum value is `32767`, and you're assigning `99789` to it. It's definitely out range. You need to explicitly typecast it to `short`:

```
short s = (short)99789;
short s1 = 100;   // this would however work
```

Although you would see strange output there. The extra bits will be truncated. It's better to use an `int` directly.

Now, in case of `float`, floating point literals are by default `double`. To get `float`, you need to append an `F` or `f` at the end. So, change that one to:

```
float f = 99.99f;
```

Comment: The other question that I have are all data types in java signed by default.Do we have the keyword unsigned as in 'C' for example?

Comment: @liv2hak. No as of Java 7 there is no unsigned type. But as I remember, Java 8 will have support for unsigned types.

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one. You need to do a type cast:

```
float f = 99.99f;
```

or

```
float f = (float)99.99;  // This is a type cast
```

You are trying to store a "large" number into a short variable. short can only store values from -32.768 to 32.767.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

in your code you are trying to assign bigger data type to smaller ones, which will end up in loss of precision, which is not allowed so you need to an explicit type cast

> > short s = (short) 99789;  and for float you have two opetions
>
> float f = 99.99f;
>
> or
>
> float f = (float)99.99;(because decimal values are double by default)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte b = 8;
    long a = 1000011334;
    int c = 76;
    short s = (short) 99789;

    float f = 99.99f;
    double d = 99979.9879;
    boolean bool = true;
    char ch = 'y';

    System.out.println("b = " + b);
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    System.out.println("c = " + c);
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
    System.out.println("f = " + f);
    System.out.println("d = " + d);
    System.out.println("bool = " + bool);
    System.out.println("ch = " + ch);
}
```

remember only those conversions are allowed which will not result in loss of precision

Answer (score 0):

```
        `float f = 99.99;`     //need to include f at last or need to type cast;
```

need to be

```
            float f = 99.99f;
            or
            float f = (float)99.99; 

       short s = 99789;      //exceeded the limit
```

The limit should be

short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

More on java data types please refer here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

A `short` is a 16 bit integer (0-65535 unsigned; −32768-32767 signed).  Your value for s is too big so it's being treated as `int` instead.

Java is seeing `99.99` as a double by default.  Simply append `f` to the end of that (`float f = 99.99f`) to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
short s = 99789;
```

short is a **16 bit** value while int is of **32 bit**.99789 or any number is predefined an **int** in java. so you have to manually cast in you are narrowing data types.

```
 short s = (short) 99789;
```

Comment: When I try `short s = 99789;`, I get an error "possible loss of precision", but `short s = 9789;` compiles fine.  I'm also using Windows, and I think I downloaded Java from Oracle's site.  But *any* `float f = nnn.nnn;` gives me a "possible loss of precisin" error.

Comment: OK, I looked it up: Any integer literal without L is treated as an `int`.  However, the compiler *will* automatically convert a **constant** `int` value to a `short` (or `byte` or `char`) if the value is in range.  But 99789 isn't.

Comment: yeah every integer literal is by default int and every decimal number is by default double and if you refer double via float , guess what ?? Loss of precision because double(bigger) was referred by float(smaller)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in:

```
short s = 99789;
```

The "short" data type has a maximum value of 32767.

99789 > 32767 which will result in a loss of precision.

Instead try:

```
int s = 99789;
```

Similarly:

```
float f = 99.99;
```

Should be a double:

```
double f = 99.99;
```

Hope that helps!